# Where can I see, if I reached my firebase quota

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console, quota

I use the freee Spark-plan to develop my app.

Since yesterday, I get weird error messages:

```
StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
Code: -13000 HttpResult: 402
```

Could that mean, some firebase quota is reached?
Where can I see which quotas are reached in my firebase console?

Appearently, free quota is 1Gb / day. There's no way I used that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "usage" tab at the top of the page in the Storage section of the Firebase console.  It is easy to find, next to Files and Rules.

If you have questions about billing and usage, please [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Thanks a ton. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To see how much of your free quota of Spark Plan you have used
Go to Firebase Console > Settings (Upper left) > Usage and Billing

[image: See here]

Also if you don't get each item in this list you can goto
Firebase Console > Develop> (Some tool like Storage or Auth) > Usage (see tabs)

I hope this will be very helpful